# RESTful program not working

Tags: java, web-services, rest, curl

I'm trying to convert this curl sentence:

curl -tlsv1.2 -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u myuser:mypass --data-binary @prueba_token.txt https://192.168.1.13/vts/rest/v1.0/tokenize

into a java program:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.DataOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.security.KeyManagementException;
        import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
        import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
        import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
        import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
        import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

        public class VormetricClientToken {



        public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
              new VormetricClientToken().DoIt();
           }//main

           private void DoIt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
              String credential = Base64.encodeBase64String("myuser:mypass".getBytes("UTF-8"));
              try{
       String https_url = "https://192.168.1.13/vts/rest/v1.0/tokenize/";
       URL myurl = new URL(https_url);
       HttpsURLConnection con = HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
       con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){      
          @Override
          public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){
             return true;
          }
       });
       String ccNum = "9876-5432-1098-7654";
       String jStr = "{\"tokengroup\" : \"pruebas\" , \"data\" :    \""+ccNum+"\", \"format\" : \"random-luhn\"}";
       con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(jStr.length()));
       con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
       byte[] ptext = jStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
       con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+credential);
       con.setRequestMethod("POST");
       con.setDoOutput(true);
       try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
          output.write(jStr.getBytes());
       }
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
       System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
       BufferedReader rd= new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
       String line = "";      
       String strResponse = "";

       while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          strResponse=strResponse+line;
       }
       con.disconnect();
       System.out.println("POST response: "+strResponse);
    }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
       System.out.println("error vormetric token client malformed:"+e);
    }catch(IOException e1){
       System.out.println("error vormetric token client ioexception:"+e1);
       e1.printStackTrace();
    }//catch
 }//doit
}//vormetricclienttoken
```

I keep receiving this message:

ioexception:java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://192.168.1.13/vts/rest/v1.0/tokenize/

I'd already tried using Httpclient but the result is the same, I know code 400 means that the web service doesn't understand the text I'm sending. But it's the same text I'm using in curl.

A little help of what could it be wrong will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Try open the logfile on the server to see how the request looks when received.

Comment: thanks, but the requests aren't logged in the web service

Comment: Then turn it on. If you can't do that in the web service, maybe the container can, e.g. Tomcat has a [RequestDumperValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Request_Dumper_Valve), or the [RequestDumperFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter).

Comment: I checked the logfile for requests but only the ones from curl are registered, the ones from java are not registered, but if my java program seems alright to you, I suppose there most be a problem with the web service and not my java program, I will try wireshark to see If I can find something more

Answer (score 0):

`DataOutputStream` is for serializing Java objects, you don't want that.

Just write to the stream returned by `con.getOutputStream()`.

---

Also, `Content-Length` is with uppercase `L`, and the value should be the length in bytes.

You declare and initialize `ptext`, but don't use it.

Change to:

```
byte[] ptext = jStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(ptext.length));
// more code
try (OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(ptext);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggest, but still getting error code 400, thank you